# Hay alguna forma de agregar iconos al alert de Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, scss, icons

Estoy modificando la apariencia de los componentes que trae ionic, pero igual necesito agregarle iconos a este alert. ya que por ejemplo creo una clase en scss. no me agrega correctamente esto, y si no es posible. quise modificar un modal. pero el problema del modal, es que cuando el usuario de click. en cualquier parte del modal este se cierre como el alert.
gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quizás esto te sirva, [icono en un alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440325/ionic-2-icon-in-alert)

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales ya habia probado es aparte, pero gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Has probado en vez de un alert, usar un modal?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales si, de hecho es lo mas factible, pero el problema es que cuando es un dispositivo movil. el modal, no se cierra cuando le doy click fuera de este. aun se permanece abierta, y quisiera saber, me faltaria algun para metro para que ese cierre.

Comment: ¿Resolviste el problema al final? Si sí, ponlo como respuesta (lo menos que vas a conseguir es un +1 mío); si no, ¿puedes poner el código que usas para generar el alert?